# display list title in one column instead of ids separated by comma

Tags: mysql

I have a table where in a column i set multi IDS of other table.
so in first table user i have for example:

| ID | ID_adress |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,4 |
| 2 | 2,3 |

And in other table where i save list address:

| ID | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ADR1 |
| 2 | ADR2 |
| 3 | ADR3 |
| 2 | ADR4 |

So how i can build a query to return an array with each row as this example?

| ID | title_ADR |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ADR1,ADR4 |
| 2 | ADR2,ADR3 |

Comment: Normalize your first table. Then you can do a proper join and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to get the list of titles.

Comment: @Barmar how exactly?

Comment: The rows should be `1, 1`, `1, 4`, `2, 2`, `2, 3`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad